# How to renumber and colour of each Clusters in Back trajectory cluster analysis in Openair package in R so that they are consistently?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, openair

I meet a problem and I don't know how to do it. I would like to output 2014-2018 back trajectories cluster results. But the clusters are not consistently from the same region in each year. I would like to renumber and color the cluster so that the region is the same. For example:
**C1- Atlantic West of UK.
C2 – English Chanel, Bay of Biscay.
C3 – Mainland France.
C4 – North Sea,
C5- Northern Atlantic and Mainland UK.
C6 – Northern coast of Germany, Belgium, and Netherlands.**

Here are my codes:

```
clust <- trajCluster(selectByDate(traj, year=2014), method = "Angle", 
                     n.cluster = 6, 
                     col = 'jet',
                     map.cols = openColours("Paired", 10))
```

I attached some previous figures from my results.
This is the results of 2014 and 2015.
[image: As you see the cluster number from the same region is different]

As you see the cluster number from the same region is different
[image]

Comment: Probably need to class your country values as factor so the order gets preserved. Or build a faceted set of maps with a single dataframe grouped by year. No way to test either of these ides without data and code.

Comment: @IRTFM, I probably know your idea, does it mean it would need more complicated work to do it? The goal of renumbering and coloring is just to make the figure clearer, if I do not renumber, it does not affect the meaning. So, if the method you mentioned is far more complicated than the cluster analysis itself, I would not do it. Thank you!